# Extension to see console.oog in vs code text editor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console, editor, extension-methods

I saw a video tutorial and the user's editor was showing the console.log results in the text editor as he was typing

```
console.log(1,2,3)   //1,2,3
```

The output was showing at the end of row

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jGAutnHuYM&ab_channel=CoderDmitri

The above is the link to the video.

Can someone tell me which extension is he using?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the extension Quokka.
In command pallete `Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + P` enter Quokka and select `New Javascript File`

You should have inline output by doing this